# Is there a way to make a mousewheel trigger the "hover" event in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, mousewheel

By default, if a user uses the mousewheel to scroll down the page, it doesn't trigger any of the hover events. Is there a way to change this so that as long as the pointer is hovering over a div, it will trigger the hover event whether the user used the mouse or the mousewheel to move it there?

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $(document).bind('mousewheel', function(e) {
    console.log(e.pageX);
    console.log(e.pageY);
    var e1 = $.Event('mouseenter');
    e1.pageX = e.pageX + 1;
    e1.pageY = e.pageY;
    $('img').trigger(e1);

    var e2 = $.Event('mousemove');
    e2.pageX = e.pageX + 1;
    e2.pageY = e.pageY;
    $('img').trigger(e2);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Edit: The above code is triggering a hover event, but it's not selecting any image in particular, it's just triggering hover events on every mouse move.

Comment: Did you try triggering a `mousemove` event after the scrolling has stopped?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by triggering a mousemove event. Is it even possible to move a mouse with javascript?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to _simulate_ a mousemove event.

Comment: I think I'm pretty close, see my last edit, let me know if you can help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work:

```
var x = 0, y = 0;

$(document).bind('mousemove', function(event) {x = event.clientX; y = event.clientY;});

$(document).bind('mousewheel', function(e1) {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random*2) ? 1 : -1;
    X = x+rand;
    Y = y;
    setTimeout(function() {$("body").trigger($.Event("mousemove", {clientX: X, clientY: Y}));}, 400);
});
```

Comment: My code is pretty similar to yours, but I want to trigger a hover event over images, and using $('img').trigger doesn't select one image in particular...

Comment: Triggering the movemouse event on body should activate the css hover event on the element the mouse is currently over.

Comment: I tried it, unfortunately it isn't triggering anything.

Comment: Ah, there was a css setting on my site that was preventing the hover, this answer is correct (there is a missing ");" at the end for people who need this solution in the future). Thanks a lot!

Comment: Fixed the missing end parenthesis.